# C++ Function Pointers in struct with 0 or 1 argument

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Here I declare a structure and I have an array of them in my class.

```
struct instruction {
    std::string disassembly;
    unsigned char operandLength;
    void* execute;
};

...

class CPU {
private:
    struct instruction opcodes[256];

    void load_n_to_b(unsigned char arg1); //0x06
    void load_c_to_b(); //0x41 

...

}
```

I have tried to initialize the opcode array but keep getting errors about "too many initializers for 'instruction'" or invalid cast from type ‘void (*)(unsigned char)’ to type ‘void*’. Because the functions can have either 0 arguments or 1 argument I do not know how to make it work in C++.

I am initializing them like so below

```
opcodes[0x06] = instruction{ "LD B, 0x%02X", 1, load_n_to_b };
opcodes[0x41] = instruction{ "LD B, C", 0, load_c_to_b };
```

Comment: Whenever you see `void *`, consider you probably have something wrong.

Comment: @NeilButterworth How else would you pass function pointers that can have zero or one varables.

Comment: Function pointers are not guaranteed to be convertible to `void *`, or vice versa, so this is moot.  As your question is about C++, you should probably  be using function objects.

Comment: @NeilButterworth How do you do function objects that have different function signatures?

Comment: If you are writing a simple CPU simulator, then don't use function pointers. Speaking as someone that wrote a fairly complete 8080 simulator and development environment in FORTRAN77 way back when.

Answer (score 1):

You hold pointer to `void` in `instruction` struct. Instead, you require function pointer.

```
void (*execute)() ;
```

It applies to `load_c_to_b` because its parameter is `void` as well. However, I would prefer `void (*execute)(void*)` because if I need a parameter I can use it by casting, otherwise, ignore it.

Comment: I cant cast to it 
src/cpu/cpu.cpp:19:64: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(unsigned char)’ to ‘void (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
  opcodes[0x06] = (instruction){ "LD B, 0x%02X", 1, load_n_to_b };

Comment: @GeneralZero hmm apparently you should study C/C++, it is a kinda common subject for both.

Comment: @GeneralZero you would have to change `void load_n_to_b(unsigned char arg1);` to `void load_n_to_b(void *arg1);`, and change `void load_c_to_b();` to `void load_c_to_b(void*);` In cases where there is no argument to pass, pass null: `inst.execute(nullptr);`. In cases where there is an argument to pass, pass it in by its address and type-cast the pointer in the function, eg: `unsigned char value = ...; inst.execute(&value); ... void load_n_to_b(void *arg1) { unsigned char arg = *static_cast<unsigned char*>(arg1); ... }` If you have more than 1 argument to pass, pass in a `struct` by pointer.